# Install APK: App not installed as app isn't compatible with your phone

Tags: java, android, apk

When I try to run my app from Android studio, it works normaly. But i cannot install the APK to my phone after Generate Signed APK -> Message on my phone is "App not installed as app isn't compatible with your phone"

**My build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\CITEK Project\\Outsource\\MNT\\Mainetti-JavaAndroid\\app\\Key.jks')
            storePassword 'citek@sap'
            keyAlias 'key0'
            keyPassword 'citek@sap'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        //noinspection ExpiredTargetSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 28

        applicationId "com.example.mycomputer.mnsystem"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
```

**My AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--suppress ALL -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.mycomputer.mnsystem">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.honeywell.decode.permission.DECODE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.symbol.emdk.permission.EMDK" />
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:name=".Handle.CheckWifi"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logomn"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logoicon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-library
            android:name ="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required ="false"/>
        <uses-library android:name="com.symbol.emdk" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            tools:replace="screenOrientation" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
     
        <receiver
            android:name=".Handle.ConnectionReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I try to Clean Project, upgrade gradle but it doesn't work

Comment: Build an APK file and try to install it manually via `adb install` then you should get an error message why installation is denied.